# GroupBy and Count with condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have an **`Exam`** table, and then **`ExamResults`** which includes all questions of a specific Exam. this table will contain the question, the answer selected, and the AnswerPower to indicate if the answer was correct or not:

- **1** (means correct),
- **0** (means wrong),
- **NULL** (means not answered and will be considered as wrong).

I am trying to get the `Count` of wrong answers of a specific exam grouped by chapters.

The following will give me the count of answers grouped by chapter, but I don't know where exactly to set the condition to count only ***wrong answers*** which can be simply `AnswerPower!=1`

```
                var query = ex.ExamResults
                .GroupBy(p => new
            {
                p.Question.Chapter.ChapterName,
                p.AnswerPower
            })
            .Select(g => new
            {
                g.Key.ChapterName,
                Mistakes = g.Count()
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `count` you can give the condition like below, Note that I have removed  `AnswerPower` from `GroupBy`

```
  var query = ex.ExamResults
        .GroupBy(p => new
    {
        p.Question.Chapter.ChapterName
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.ChapterName,
        Mistakes = g.Count(x => x.AnswerPower!=1),
        CorrectAnswers = g.Count(x => x.AnswerPower==1)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ex.ExamResults
   .GroupBy(p => new
            {
                p.Question.Chapter.ChapterName,
                p.AnswerPower
            })
    .Where(p => p.AnswerPower!=1)
    .Select(g => new
            {
                g.Key.ChapterName,
                Mistakes = g.Count()
            });
```

Comment: There is no direct `p.AnswerPower` in `Where` and I think you mean `p.Key.AnswerPower!=1`